# Get directory of file when deployed on server

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my solution I have multiple projects and in Project A I want to System.IO.File.ReadAllText(string directory) from a file in project B however I do not want to hardcode the path as this will change once deployed on the hosting server. I've set the Copy Always on the file but cannot use the `Path.Combine(GetCurrentDirectory)` as the directory will be different, it will be from a different Project in my Solution file. How can I go around this?

Ive also tried

```
System.String.Format(@"{0}bin\{1}", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, filename);
```

however the problem is that the file in project b is not the BaseDirectory.

Comment: CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory makes sense *only* for desktop applications. There's no reason to access anything in the `bin` folder of a *web application*. It's also a very bad idea from a security perspective - you'd have to use elevated priviledges to allow the web application to access files in `bin`. Put any resources/assets you need in a folder and use Server.MapPath to map relative URLs to the absolute file location.

Comment: Web application project templates have an App_Data folder. Why don't you use it?